# The table view custom cell are not dealloc/release when I called the UITableView method "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths"x

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have create custom cell in table view. Each cell is different in terms of UI. I have craetd three cell and identifier for each cell is different. The custom table view cell are not released when I called the method "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths". Here is the link of my project source code

http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/486016/TableVIewTestSample-zip.html

or

http://www.2shared.com/file/PgExc8W_/TableVIewTestSample.html

When run the code click on "Push" button on the screen and then wait 4 second at the 2nd screen and click back button. The cell are not released.

Can anybody run the code and suggest any fix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue exist in iOS 7.0.0 to iOS 7.0.2. The cells do not release when we perform the "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths" method. This issue is solved in iOS 7.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your code but cells aren't necessarily released when you reload. Cells are built to be re-used, so just reloading the data doesn't necessarily free the old cells. (There's no reason to free and re-create a cell if you've already created enough cells.)

In general if you create a tableView and scroll around you shouldn't see any cells released. You should see them released only when you nuke the tableView (that's when it's sure it won't need them again) and a few other situations.

(On the other hand, you might just be leaking the cells.)

Comment: Can you please look at the code? I am using instrument and When I view controller release then the cell should also be released but it is not.

Comment: Not super-excited to download something from "Mega-upload," sorry. :/

Comment: Here is the upload link to 2shared. http://www.2shared.com/file/PgExc8W_/TableVIewTestSample.html

Comment: I have found link https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=582 which says that it is apple bug. He was facing same problem which I am facing.